# Need help implementing Socket.io into an already existing project

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I've been working on a project recently where users make posts to find people to play video games with. Up until now, I've been lazy and simply set the post feed to refresh every two seconds on a setTimeout, but it slows down interactions with the server after a while, so I've decided to learn Socket.io to remedy this.

I'm not sure how to implement Socket.io into my project though. I've tried the official setup guide found [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io) as well as an unofficial guide found [here](https://vexxhost.com/resources/tutorials/mean-socket-io-integration-tutorial/) but neither seem to work for me.

According to the official Socket.io guide, this is what I need to implement for it to work with my Express server:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function(){ /* … */ });
server.listen(3000);
```

And this is what my server.js file currently looks like, with the section between the multiple slashes being where I tried to implement the above code:

```
var express = require('express')
  , passport = require('passport')
  , util = require('util')
  , SteamStrategy = require('passport-steam').Strategy
  , http = require('http')
  , socketio = require('socket.io');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = require('./config');


mongoose.connect(config.MONGO_URI);

mongoose.connection.on('error', function() {
  console.error('MongoDB Connection Error. Please make sure that MongoDB is running.');
});

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
  done(null, obj);
});

passport.use(new SteamStrategy({
    returnURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/steam/return',
    realm: 'http://localhost:3000',
    apiKey: '123123123'
  },
  function(identifier, profile, done) {
    process.nextTick(function () {
      profile.identifier = identifier;
      return done(null, profile);
    });
  }
));

///////////////////HERE////////////////////////

var server = require('http').createServer(express);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function(){ /* … */ });

///////////////////HERE////////////////////////

// express config
app.configure(function() {
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.use(express.static('app'));
  app.use(express.logger());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.session({ secret: '*****' }));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.set('socketio', io);
  app.set('server', server);
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", this.address().port, app.settings.env);
});

require('./routes')(app, passport);
```

---

My issue is that when I try to start my Node server, it tells me 'listener must be a function' about the following line:

```
var server = require('http').createServer(express);
```

When I tried to add parentheses after my express requirement like so:

```
var express = require('express')()
```

It tells me that that object is not a function, even though that's how they do it in their official example.

---

How can I properly implement Socket.io into my project? Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: What does `npm ls` show? You may have a really old version of Express installed (e.g. 2.x).

Comment: Can you try server.listen instead of app.listen?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your Express `app`, not the value of `require('express')`, which just returns the function that *creates* Express apps, to `createServer()`.